# How configure maven-war-plugin for tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

I can not generate proper WAR file for Tomcat.

I am using MAVEN 3.6.1, Java 12.0.1 and IDE Eclipse. My app is working fine when I run it in eclipse (Run as > Spring Boot App) but the problem is when I am trying to run my WAR file after generate it.

I am doing java -jar .war  and I am getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.blw.linemanager.Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blw.linemanager.Application
```

I was googling and reading stackoverflow cause I found many post about it but still can not run it. What I am doing wrong?

After some reading I figured out that I have some how configure maven-war-plugin (am I right?) and in pom I did some changes but it does not help.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>bwl</groupId>
    <artifactId>LineManager</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.blw.linemanager.Application</start-class>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>LineManager</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <classpathPrefix>${project.build.directory}/WEB-INF/classes</classpathPrefix>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.blw.linemanager.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.directory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also because on the beginning I was getting error 'no main manifest attribute' I add it and now it looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven ${maven.version}
Build-Jdk: ${java.version}
```

Is my way of think wrong? Should I be able to run .war file as java -jar .war or this is missunderstanding?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer. Why are you using a web.xml? I used to have the maven-war-plugin as simple as ` <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`.

Comment: @Meziane that is my last pom configuration I found it somewhere on the internet. But I was using  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> but that does not help me at all.

Comment: Let me know more about what you have: it is very simple to get it work.

Comment: Start with a simple pom: you just need the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to start your application as a `Spring Boot Application` and `maven-war-plugin`.

Comment: I edited post to updated pom.xml right now you can see everything from my pom. Each piece I added cause I found something on internet what makes me think that I have to add it.

Comment: Keep things simple. Use the following as `parent`fro your project:  
`<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>`
and as `plugins`
`<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
   </plugin>
`

Comment: add the following BOM to your `pom`:
`
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
`

Comment: @Meziane when I follow your comment, when I generate WAR and deploy it to Tomcat I can see that on the list of Deployed App my app appears as not running, so is not what I want also.

Comment: You must have some thing wrong: did you have a `web.xml`?

Comment: I am at home and I am using my mobile to write this comment.
It is better to get a working spring boot application from here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/
You have to make it ServletInitializer aware.
If you want I can help you tomorrow: it's now 19:39 localtime.

Comment: Thanks @Meziane you help a lot. I made it. It works. I still can not run .war file from command line with "java -jar file.war" but when i deployed it to Tomcat it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that.
Could you please accept my answer if aÍ add one with my comments?

Comment: sure, I will do it

Comment: That&#39;s very kind. Many thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer: please check it and accept it.
If you want my advice change your pseudo: you may need your SO-Account for your career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to get a working spring boot application from [here](https://start.spring.io/) to avoid versions conflicts and the like.
For a `war`-file deployment (into a local tomcat for example), your application must extend  `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class, args);
      }

      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class);
      }
    }
```

Change in your `pom` the  `packaging` to `war`.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

To generate a `war`-file you need just the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And yes you don't need the `maven-war-plugin`. Just for testing purposes let's annotate our application with `@RestController` and introduce a simple endpoint:

```
    @RestController
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
      @RequestMapping(value = "/")
      public String hello() {
        return "Hello World from Tomcat";
      }
    }
```

In the `Local terminal` (in eclipse Ctrl+Alt+T)  just enter `mvn package` than copy the generated `war`-file from `target` folder, paste it under the `webapps` folder of your local Tomcat, request http://localhost:8080/{your-application-name} and you should see the message `Hello World from Tomcat`.
Now you can add the dependencies you need and continue coding.

Comment: No that is not problem also. I edited post to add my main class

Answer (score 0):

Add packaging type with version detail in pom.xml like

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

or

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then, append build tag to define name of jar / war like,

```
<build>
    <finalName>YOUR-APP_NAME</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, run your application with goal

clean package

to create jar/war in target folder.

Rename your war file to ROOT like ROOT.war

Last step to copy your created jar/war in tomcat webapps folder and start tomcat.

Comment: That does not solve my issue, only broke my Tomcat server.